# How to get max() element from List in Guava

Tags: java, guava

Let's say we have a Collection of Items:

```
class Item {
    public String title;
    public int price;
}

List<Item> list = getListOfItems();
```

I would like to get an Item with a maximum price out of that list with Guava library (with [Ordering](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html), I presume). I mean something similar to this Groovy code:

```
list.max{it.price}
```

How do I do that? How efficient is it?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
Ordering<Item> o = new Ordering<Item>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Item left, Item right) {
        return Ints.compare(left.price, right.price);
    }
};
return o.max(list);
```

It's as efficient as it can be: it iterates through the items of the list, and returns the first of the Items having the maximum price: O(n).

Comment: if price is not int. Are in guava way to use this approach?

Comment: The type of the price is irrelevant. You just need to provide an ordering that compares items by price. Let's say it's BigDecimal, you would use `return left.price.compareTo(right.price)`.

Answer (score 38):

According to JB's answer, you can also use some shorthand when working with values which have natural order, for example:

```
Ordering.<Integer> natural().max(listOfIntegers);
```

See [Ordering.natural()](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#natural()) for details.

Answer (score 16):

You can do this without Guava.

Collections provides [`min`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min-java.util.Collection-) and [`max`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-) methods that operate on any Collection, including overloads taking comparators.  Here we use the Java 8 Comparator static methods with a lambda to concisely specify a comparator, but before Java 8 you can use an anonymous class:

```
Item max = Collections.max(list, Comparator.comparingInt(i -> i.price));
```

These methods will throw NoSuchElementException if the collection is empty.

---

Java 8 streams provide [`min`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#min-java.util.Comparator-) and [`max`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-) functions taking a comparator.  These functions return `Optional<T>` to gracefully handle the stream being empty.  The static methods in Comparator are useful for concisely specifying comparators, including the common case of the natural ordering.  For this question, you'd use

```
Optional<Item> max = list.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(i -> i.price));
```

This will work for any stream source, which includes all Collection implementations, as well as other things like files, and makes it easy to compute the max of a subset of a collection by filtering the stream.  If you have a large collection and an expensive comparator (e.g., String's natural ordering), you can use a parallel stream.

(Aside: ideally Stream would provide `min` and `max` overloads taking no argument when the stream type implements Comparable.  Unfortunately Java doesn't support conditionally exposing methods based on a type parameter, and it isn't worth introducing a new StreamOfComparable interface extending Stream just for this case.)