# How to get max and min values from a multiple column collection in java

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I have a collection class (a `java.util.ArrayList`). When I go through the collection and print the lines, the output looks like this:

```
x = 1997 y = 1700
x = 1996 y = 1800  
x = 1992 y = 1150
x = 1994 y = 1300 
x = 1993 y = 1000
x = 1995 y = 1650
```

How do I get *max x*, *min x*, *max y*, and *min y* from this collection?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get max() element from List in Guava](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758982/how-to-get-max-element-from-list-in-guava)

Comment: Iterate over the collection. Store the first value in a variable and check with and if condition if the next value is bigger/smaller if true, store this value in the variable. After the iteration you have the min or max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int minX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int maxX = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

int minY = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int maxY = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

for (A a: collection) {
    if (a.x < minX)
       minX = a.x;
    if (a.x > maxX)
       maxX = a.x;

    if (a.y < minY)
       minY = a.y;
    if (a.y > maxY)
       maxY = a.y;

}
```