# guava. find element in Collection by criteria

Tags: java, collections, guava

I have this code.

```
CommentModel lastUserComment = comments.iterator().next();
        for (CommentModel comment : comments) {
            if (comment.getCreationtime().after(lastUserComment.getCreationtime())) {
                lastUserComment = comment;
            }
        }
```

I want to replace it using guava.

If getCreationtime() returned int I could to use something like this:
[How to get max() element from List in Guava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758982/how-to-get-max-element-from-list-in-guava)

Are there in Guava  tool for resolving my problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just compare the times.

```
final Ordering<CommentModel> o = new Ordering<CommentModel>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final CommentModel left, final CommentModel right) {
        return left.getCreationTime().compareTo(right.getCreationTime());
    }
};
return o.max(comments);
```