# Min/Max of object.attribute in a list of object with guava

Tags: java, guava

Let's take a list of `Person` defined as

- Name
- Surname
- Age

I want the max(age) in a `List<Person>`.

I could iterate on this list and manually keep the max :

```
Integer max = null;
for(Person p : list) {
  if(max == null || max < p.getAge()) {
    max = p.getAge();
  }
  return max;
}
```

But I feel that there might exist a combination of Guava methods which can do it for me. If I write a `Function<Person, Integer>`, is there a ready-to-use method to get the max from the list?

Comment: Uh, what is `age`? I take it this is an `Integer` but why not make it an `int`?

Comment: I like object because they can be null. If the age is not filled, I prefer getting a NPE (and be forced to add a constraint in DB) instead of having 0.

Comment: Uh, OK... But then why not force the code to have a value inserted in a first place? Hint: with null columns, how do you reliably use `NOT IN`?

Comment: @fge It is a personal choice. On all the beans of my current project, I only write the attributes and generate Getters/Setters + a default constructor. I personnally hate Setters that do other than just setting a value. For `NOT IN`, I admit that I have never tried to use it on an optional column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11759056/991954) answer. You can use [`Ordering.max()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#max-java.lang.Iterable-)

```
Ordering<People> o = new Ordering<People>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(People left, People right) {
        return Ints.compare(left.getAge(), right.getAge());
    }
};

return o.max(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Guava, but I think it would come out to be more convoluted than a cleaner version of your solution, namely:

```
int max = -1;

for (People p : list) {
    if (p.getAge() > max)
        max = p.getAge();
}
```

By the way, it may make more sense to call your class `Person`, since it is representing a single *person*, and not a group of *people*.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `Function<Person, Integer>` (called `getAge`, say), this would just be:

```
Integer maxAge = Ordering.natural().max(Iterables.transform(people, getAge));
```