# TreeSet doesn't allow duplicates of words' lengths

Tags: java, comparator, treeset

I need to save some Words in a TreeSet and print them depending on thier length where words with smaller length come first and if 2 Words have the same length, then both should be printed in any order, but my code skips the next word with the same length and prints only the first word with that length.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
           
   static Comparator<String> comparator = Comparator.comparing(s -> s.length());

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Set<String> buch = new TreeSet <>(comparator);
      buch.addAll(List.of("a", "test", "ab", "z", "lol", "aaa"));
      buch.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont use `TreeSet` , because if consider Your `2 Words have the same length` as duplicates and that class prevent duplicates that has the same value ( from the comparator ) witch is the length ! Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54738425/14629458) answer if you have to keep it a `TreeSet`

Comment: Can't i modify the Comparator in a way that makes this work?

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your *specific* technical issue.

Answer (score 2):

You could change the comparator to something like:

```
static Comparator<String> comparator = Comparator.comparing(String::length)
                                                 .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

Comment: @YasserCHENIK I would take it with a grain of salt ;-), and ask what scenario forces someone to stick with the `TreeSet`.

Comment: I should use it according to the question i'm trying to solve :)

Answer (score 1):

Like someone said, a set doesn't allow duplicates.  In your case, since you are using the length of the string, you may have strings that have the same length.

But here's an example of using a comparator with `TreeSet`.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Set<String> buch = new TreeSet <>((s1,s2)->s1.length()-s2.length());
      buch.addAll(List.of("a", "test", "ab", "cd", "z", "lol", "aaa"));
      buch.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it will lose entries with the same difference in length to another pairing already added to the set.

Comment: The author could use array list and sort it using the above comparator.