# Problems with Java Generics with comparable

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I'm trying to do a very simple class in order to return the min value of a collections. This is my code:

```
public class Min_Comparable <T extends Comparable<? super T>> {

    public  T min(Collection<? extends T> c){
        Iterator<? extends T> it = c.iterator();
        T min = it.next();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            if(min.compareTo(it.next()) > 0 ){
                min = it.next();
            }
        }
        return min;
    }
}
```

This is my main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Min_Comparable test = new Min_Comparable();
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(6);
        list.add(0);
        list.add(5);
        list.add(2);

        System.out.println(test.min(list));

    }
}
```

This is my errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:854)
    at MidTerm.Min_Comparable.min(Min_Comparable.java:16)
    at MidTerm.Main.main(Main.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

So my question is: very is the mistake? I have no error in the wildcards or generics, i think that everything is casting so what am i doing wrong?

Comment: This is a statement, not a question.

Comment: The main problem I can see is that you're using `next` twice for each `hasNext`.

Comment: @PaulBoddington should be right ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `next` twice, when `hasNext` has only been checked once. Hence the `NoSuchElementException`. Try this instead.

```
while(it.hasNext()){
    T next = it.next();     
    if(min.compareTo(next) > 0 ){
        min = next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling next() twice

```
if(min.compareTo(it.next()) > 0 ){
            min = it.next();
 }
```

This advances the iterator twice.  You want to only call next once and save it as to a variable

```
 T next = it.next();
 if(min.compareTo(next) > 0 ){
            min = next;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758982/how-to-get-max-element-from-list-in-guava) if you would like to see a really simple & powerful implementation based on Guava :)